# spoj http://www.spoj.com/problems/JULKA/

Tags: c++

```
    //explain below for loop what is actually being done in this loop//
     for(i=k-1, j=a=f=0; i>=0; i--)
     {
         b = (a*10 + temp[i]-'0') / 2; //explain
         a = (a*10 + temp[i]-'0') % 2;//explain
        if(b) f = 1;//explain
        if(f) klaudia[j++] = b+'0';//explain
    }
     if(!j) j++;//explain
     klaudia[j] = 0;//explain

     for(i=len1-1, j=len2-1, k=c=0; i>=0; i--, j--, k++)
     {
         a = total[i]-'0';//explain
         b = j>=0? diff[j]-'0' : 0;//explain
        if(a < b+c)
       {
             temp[k] = (10+a-b-c) + '0';//explain
             c = 1;//explain           }
        else
       {
          temp[k] = a-b-c + '0';//explain
          c = 0;//explain
       }
  }
  temp[k] = 0;//explain
```

explain what is being done in both the for loop above why we are dividing and modulating by 2. what is the signifinace of adding 0

Comment: @YuHao: Perhaps he was pointing out (repeatedly) that he used to be a fan of Sarah Palin (if so, editing was probably a good move).

Comment: @YuHao corrected the spelling now  man can anyone please explain the for loop now

Comment: @codingisfun Back on topic, how is what you posted related to the problem you linked? Did you just find that code somewhere online (if so, I wouldn't visit that website again...)

Comment: The reason that '0' is being added and subtracted is to convert number from ascii to it's numeric representation and back again. This is likely some form of large integer solution (i.e. integers larger than `long long`). The rest of it is pretty arcane and some of the instructions are unnecessary. I suggest it attempts to solve the problem that your link references.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is dividing the decimal number expressed as a string in temp[] by 2.  The /2 is literally to divide one digit by 2, and the %2 is to take the remainder to apply to the next digit - which is why it is then multiplied by 10.

Additions and subtractions by '0' are to convert single digits between a raw number and its ASCII representation as a character.